# How to store a specific object's member function of known signature in a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, function, functional-programming, std

What is the recommended way to store a reference to a non-static *member function* of a specific signature *on some object instance*? In a way where the calling code needs not to know of the object's class (i.e. no casting), just that the function is the correct signature.

For example, if there are two different classes with functions of the same `void(int)` signature, like

```
class Foo {
public:
  int myInt;
  
  void multMyInt(int multiplier) {
    myInt *= multiplier;
  }
};

class Bar {
public:
  bool isBig;
  
  void setMySize(int size) {
    isBig = size > 100;
  }
};
```

What should this code look like?

```
int main() {
  Foo* myFoo = new Foo();
  Bar* myBar = new Bar();

  int x = 10;

  callIntFunc(x, /* myFoo->multMyInt() */);
  callIntFunc(x, /* myBar->setMySize() */);
}

// Calls any function which matches void(int).
void callIntFunc(int inInt, /* function stored in some way */) {
  // call given function with inInt as the parameter
}
```

What is the recommended approach to doing this using standard library only?

p.s. Apologies if this is a repeat question. I have searched in any terms that came to mind, and couldn't find it.

Comment: You could look at lambdas or `std::function`.

Comment: From reading std::function basics, I only saw something like `std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> functionToCall = &Foo::multMyInt;`, but that requires knowledge of `Foo` at the time it's called. 

I am sure another way is possible and easily findable, it's just that my reading comprehension of C++ documentation and code is still at a fairly low level. 

Hence this question.

Comment: Read the related things as well, in particular `bind()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have to store not only the pointer to the member function but also the object which the function should access, you need a way to store both in a single kind of object.

As C++ has lambda functions you simply can take them and use them like in the following example modified from your code.

```
class Foo {
    public:
        int myInt;

        void multMyInt(int multiplier) {
            std::cout << "Calls multMyInt" << std::endl;
            myInt *= multiplier;
        }
};

class Bar {
    public:
        bool isBig;

        void setMySize(int size) {
            std::cout << "Calls setMySize" << std::endl;
            isBig = size > 100; 
        }
};

// Calls any function which matches void(int).
void callIntFunc(int inInt, auto& func )
{
    func(inInt);
}


int main() {
    Foo* myFoo = new Foo();
    Bar* myBar = new Bar();

    auto multMyInt = [myFoo](int parm){ myFoo->multMyInt(parm);};
    auto setMySize = [myBar](int parm){ myBar->setMySize(parm);};

    int x = 10;



    callIntFunc(x, multMyInt);
    callIntFunc(x, setMySize);
}
```

In times before C++11 you have to use `std::bind` but that is really not longer needed.

Instead of using `auto` in connection with lambda, you can also go with `std::function` which results in:

```
// Calls any function which matches void(int).
void callIntFunc(int inInt, std::function<void(int)>& func )
{
    func(inInt);
}


int main() {
    Foo* myFoo = new Foo();
    Bar* myBar = new Bar();

    std::function<void(int)> multMyInt = [myFoo](int parm){ myFoo->multMyInt(parm);};
    std::function<void(int)> setMySize = [myBar](int parm){ myBar->setMySize(parm);};

    int x = 10;



    callIntFunc(x, multMyInt);
    callIntFunc(x, setMySize);
}
```

The templated version which uses `auto` needs some more program memory as it generates for each function type a new instance, but it is fast.

The `std::function` version needs less program space but results in a bit runtime overhead. It depends on your needs what you prefer!

Update from comments:

There is nothing special regarding the scope in case of using lambdas as in every other situation where you use pointers or references. But you have to take care:

- if you capture by reference, the referenced object must be alive if you call the function / lambda.
- if you capture a copy of the object, you get a new independent copy. As this, it is valid as long the lambda is alive, but you reference to a copy and not the original object.

What is the type of `auto`:

Every lambda results in a new type. The type itself is always hidden and generated by the implementation. That is why you have to use `auto`.

Comment: Thank you! In this case, what is the actual variable type of `auto multMyInt` and `auto setMySize`?

Also, are the limitations in terms of scope? As in, would those two variables be safe to use outside of `main` in this case?

Comment: @goose_lake it is the type of the lambda. You cannot spell types of lambdas, you *must* use `auto` if you want to store lambdas in variables. You can pass lambdas to function templates because this deduces the type. But if you want something with an explicitly spelled type, be it a variable or a function parameter, you have to convert the lambda to `std::function` (or to a regular function pointer --- not applicable here).

Comment: @goose_lake: I updated regarding your scope question

Comment: @Klaus Thank you for the clear explanation, and the considerations/differences. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front). It does the same thing as a custom lambda suggested in the other answer, but the syntax is less verbose.

```
auto func = std::bind_front(&Foo::multMyInt, myFoo);
func(42);
```

Note that we pass the class *pointer* as the second argument. If we instead pass by value, the class instance will be copied into the functor.

Here `auto` expands to some unspecified type, but you can replace it with `std::function<void(int)>`.

Comment: Thank you! Quite a clear syntax and good solution. Would mark as correct if it was possible to mark more than one answer. 

I like how there are multiple ways, and would love to understand the subtle differences between them in time.

Still need to properly understand how functions are represented in memory for this, I assume.

Comment: @goose_lake There might be more reasons, but first we had `std::bind` which was left behind in favor of lambdas. Now we also have some convenience functions to deal with lambdas like this one for the most common use-cases.